# Трудности программирования ботов

Tags: java, html, парсер

Есть сайт, у сайта есть блок с id регионов, городов и т.п, но этот блок скрыт пока на него не нажмешь мышкой. Мне надо извлечь эти id.

С начала я извлек с помощью HttpURLConnection класса их html страницу, но так как этот блок скрыт пока на него не нажмешь мышкой, мне в html странице не приходят исходники данного блока чтобы я мог его распарсить.

Есть решения данной проблемы ?

Кстати когда я открываю консоль разработчика содержимое этого блока можно найти и посмотреть, даже если он скрыт.

Comment: Не уверен, но может быть этот блок подгружается одним из js скриптом расположенном на странице.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не приходят в сорцах - значит подгружаются скриптом.
Блок в консоли может быть просто пустым.

Либо подгружайте как HTML-страницу (`WebView`?) и там заставьте `JS` подгрузить блок, либо сразу узнайте адрес с загружаемыми данными и подтягивайте оттуда.
Первый вариант для извращенцев, конечно :)

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Пересмотрел еще раз, действительно блок пуст.

Comment: @AndreySibirkin, всегда пожалуйста!